# Error while submitting a spark job using spark-jobserver

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I face following error occasionally while submitting job. This error goes away if I remove the rootdir of filedao, datadao and sqldao. That means I have to restart the job-server and re-upload my jar.

```
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "result": {
    "message": "Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/1995aeba-com.spmsoftware.distributed.job.TestJob#-1370794810]] after [10000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type \"spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$StartJob\".",
    "errorClass": "akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException",
    "stack": ["akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:604)", "akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)", "scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)", "scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)", "scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)", "akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:331)", "akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:282)", "akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:286)", "akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:238)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"]
  }
}
```

My config file is as follows:

```
# Template for a Spark Job Server configuration file
# When deployed these settings are loaded when job server starts
#
# Spark Cluster / Job Server configuration
# Spark Cluster / Job Server configuration
spark {
  # spark.master will be passed to each job's JobContext
  master = <spark_master>

  # Default # of CPUs for jobs to use for Spark standalone cluster
  job-number-cpus = 4

  jobserver {
    port = 8090

    context-per-jvm = false
    context-creation-timeout = 100 s
    # Note: JobFileDAO is deprecated from v0.7.0 because of issues in
    # production and will be removed in future, now defaults to H2 file.
    jobdao = spark.jobserver.io.JobSqlDAO

    filedao {
      rootdir = /tmp/spark-jobserver/filedao/data
    }

    datadao {
      rootdir = /tmp/spark-jobserver/upload
    }

    sqldao {
      slick-driver = slick.driver.H2Driver

      jdbc-driver = org.h2.Driver

      rootdir = /tmp/spark-jobserver/sqldao/data

      jdbc {
        url = "jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/spark-jobserver/sqldao/data/h2-db"
        user = ""
        password = ""
      }

      dbcp {
        enabled = false
        maxactive = 20
        maxidle = 10
        initialsize = 10
      }
    }
    result-chunk-size = 1m
    short-timeout = 60 s    
  }

  context-settings {
    num-cpu-cores = 2           # Number of cores to allocate.  Required.
    memory-per-node = 512m         # Executor memory per node, -Xmx style eg 512m, #1G, etc.

  }

}

akka {
  remote.netty.tcp {
    # This controls the maximum message size, including job results, that can be sent
    # maximum-frame-size = 200 MiB
  }
}

# check the reference.conf in spray-can/src/main/resources for all defined settings
spray.can.server.parsing.max-content-length = 250m
```

I am using `spark-2.0-preview` version.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error before and was related with timeout, for sure is an syncronus request (sync=true) togheter you must provide the timeout (in seconds) who is a value relative with how long it takes to process your request.

This an example how the request should look like:

```
curl -k --basic -d '' 'http://localhost:5050/jobs?appName=app&classPath=Main&context=test-context&sync=true&timeout=40'
```

if your request needs more than 40 seconds maybe you also need to modify the application.conf located on

```
spark-jobserver-master/job-server/src/main/resources/application.conf
```

ànd on the **spray.can.server** section modify:

```
idle-timeout = 210 s
request-timeout = 200 s
```